# Modifying array defined in enclosing scope in lambda

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

I have following code, and it rightly refuses to compile with the error *Local variable numberArray defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final*

```
InputReader reader = new InputReader(System.in);
int numInputs = reader.nextInt();
int[] numberArray = new int[numInputs];

IntStream.range(0, numInputs).forEach(i -> {
    numberArray[i] = reader.nextInt();
});
```

However, this piece of code compiles and works without any error, though here also, I'm essentially doing the same thing, modifying *inputArray* inside lambda.

```
public int[] reverse(int[] inputArray) {
    IntStream.range(0, inputArray.length/2).forEach(i-> {
        int temp = inputArray[i];
        inputArray[i] = inputArray[inputArray.length-1-i];
        inputArray[inputArray.length-1-i] = temp;
    });
    return inputArray;
}
```

Any idea why this discrepancy exists?

Comment: In the first case, do you have any assignment to numberArray  after the loop?

Comment: `int[] numberArray = new int[numInputs];` what happen to `numberArray `  before this line?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod numberArray is declared and defined in this line

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Nothing can happen to `numberArray` *before* the line that declares it.

Comment: Try changing line to `final int[] numberArray = new int[numInputs];` and compiler will tell you why it didn't consider the variable *effectively* final.

Comment: @chandra, you are correct, assignment to numberArray after the loop was the issue. Please post this as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure numberArray is not changed after the loop. It would not be considered effectively final in that case.

```
numberArray = ...
```

Comment: which one `numberArray[i]` or `numberArray` ?